# Is there a way to export chat history in Skype 5.2.x for OS X?

Tags: macos, skype, history, export

I'm currently running 5.2.x on OS X 10.6.8 and I need to some deep searching of the past history in a conversation with a colleague. Skype tells me the term I'm looking for is in the long-running chat we've had, but good luck getting it to show you the specific chat entry in time without manually scrolling backwards through months and months of back-and-forth.

I'd like to export the conversation as some format I can access programmatically (HTML, XML, etc.). The HTML export options that used to be present in Skype for OS X seem to have disappeared as of the 5.0 release.

**Is there a way to export chat history in Skype 5.2.x for OS X?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the [OS X Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) installed you can use this terminal command:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/<YOUR SKYPENAME>/main.db "SELECT author,timestamp, body_xml FROM messages WHERE dialog_partner = '<OTHER SKYPENAME>'" > ~/Desktop/skype_chat_history.txt
```

Comment: This is *excellent*! That you can interface with their DB using sqlite3 is a very good bit of information. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice. From this I found during 2012 I spend 4.7 days talking to my SO.

Answer (score 1):

It's a complete UI fail that you can't search within a conversation.

This isn't what you're after, but one approach I've taken is to copy and paste the entire conversation into a real editor and search there.

Comment: Actually getting the Skype UI to show me the whole conversation takes...a long, long time. So long I killed it after an hour of watching it spin. But not a bad approach really.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice web-based (and thus platform-independent) tool for exporting Skype history: [skypebrowser.com](http://www.skypebrowser.com/)

It's quite handy if you don't want to mess with SQL or install any third-party software.

Comment: Hmm. You have to give you Skype database to a third party website. That's not a great thing.

Comment: @IanC. I'm not saying it's the safest way, I'm saying it's the easiest and most convenient one. You obviously shouldn't trust any third-party software to access confidential data (not just your skype database; any browser addon that displays your email messages, prints a page you're viewing, etc.) But there are many cases when you can choose convenience over safety.